# How to check and also set variable synchronously in Kotlin?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin

I have a mutable nullable property. I'd like to check in a method if its value is null, if so, set it to a newly created object. Then I'd call a method of the property (old or new, but existing object).

And this should be thread-safe. How can I do that in Kotlin?

With `.let`, I cannot reassign the property. When using `synchronized(...)` or `.withLock`, between the assignment and invocation, the thread can be interrupted by another. Or at least the IDE says so, smart cast is impossible. I don't understand, why is `synchronized` there if it doesn't synchronize the block?

```
var starterTask: AsyncTask<MyData, Void, Void>? = null

fun start() {
    make it thread safe {
        if (starterTask == null) {
            starterTask = a child of AsyncTask()
        }
        starterTask.execute(this) // <- no !! operator
    }
}
```

In Java, if I locked an object with `synchronized`, I could check, assign, invoke an object, everyone was happy. Can I do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: if you posted sample code it would be clearer. Smart cast inside `synchronized` block doesn't work because despite you knowing this is the only place where variable is modified, compiler doesn't know that and still have to assume there could be another setter which would make your `synchronized` block fail.

Comment: Sorry, what? That is why synchronization there: we're telling the compiler that the block must be executed without interruption. We put locks so if any other thread would access the resource, then it waits. Why would we do all this if we gain nothing because the compiler wouldn't care?

Comment: Even if your variable is accessed in a synchronized block it doesn't mean that the same variable cannot be accessed from other non-protected places in the code. E.g. after your "make it thread safe"-block one could write `starterTask = null`

Comment: Could you replace all that code with a `by lazy`, and get the compiler to do it all for you?

Comment: @gpunto That's what locks are for. It doesn't matter what statements are there before/after the protected block.

Comment: A lock only protects a block of _code_ from being executed concurrently, it doesn't protect the accessed _data_ from being modified outside.

Comment: @Ilya That's why we lock the data itself.

Comment: You don't lock the data. Either your object has some internal synchronization mechanism (like the synchronized lazy delegate) or you cannot guarantee that a *shared* variable is never going to be accessed unsafely.

Comment: @gpunto `synchronized(...)` can be used on the data too. It should mean the access to that object is locked, and no one else can access it until the `synchronized` block is fully executed and then the lock is released. Does Kotlin's `synchronized` means something else?

Comment: You can pass any object you want to `synchronized`. That object will be used *as* lock, but it doesn't mean that the object itself is locked. It only means that every "user" of `synchronized(obj)` with that same obj, will wait for the lock to be released before entering the synchronized block. This doesn't stop anyone from just mutating obj without calling synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) for that:

```
val starterTask = lazy { a child of AsyncTask() }

fun start() {
    starterTask.execute(this)
```

The default thread safety mode is `SYNCHRONIZED`, so it matches your needs.

Comment: This might work, thanks. (Actually, I figured out I won't need this part in my app..). However, as I understand `lazy` creates a "local copy" of the variable, then uses synchronization. I already knew that if I make a local variable copy of my data, I won't need null check on that, since the local one can't be modified by other threads. But you didn't need to do that in Java. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't understand what bothers you. Perhaps you better ask a new question for that. Of course, as *delegation* implies, there comes a second object into play. If you use IntelliJ or the like, navigate just into the implemation of `lazy` (Ctrl+B), that might clarify things. There you will see, that the actual value is delivered without the need of synchronisation, once it is calculated.

Comment: This was a more theoretical question. Test-and-set-then-use is the most basic part of synchronization, atomic operations etc., I just wanted to know it would be possible in another way. Global access + locks are different than the local copy pattern.

Comment: Ok, I've looked at it closer. This is not what I need, you changed my code completely. `start()` will be invoked a lot, about half of the time a new object should be created. `starterTask`'s role in my snippet is not just an implementation of `lateinit`. `lazy` peroperty would store one instance of the task, then later work with it. `lazy` block doesn't prevent the nullable case.